# Not able to get current logged in user in django model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to get current logged in user through my model so that I can only see the current user in my order page dropdown:

1. I have gone through a lot of documents which state that it is not that easy or feasible to get current logged in user in model.
2. I have tried other method like getting AUTH_USER_MODEL but it is returning admin level users as well so not solving the problem.
3. I am also sending the current logged in user from my views file but dont know how to access it inside form class, able to access it in **init** but dont know how it can be accessed in class.

**models.py :**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpRequest

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    #customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20,default= 'PENDING')
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer.id)
```

**forms.py :**

```
class createorderform(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self._instance=kwargs.pop('instance',None)
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    #def __init__(self,instance):
    #    self.user = instance
    #    super().__init__(instance)

    class Meta:
        model=Order
        fields="__all__"
        exclude=['status']
```

**Views.py**

```
def placeorder(request,i):
    try:
        products = Product.objects.all()
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=i)
        print("Customer:",customer)
        #form=createorderform(prod=products,cust=customer)
        form=createorderform(instance=customer)
        #form=createorderform()
        if(request.method=='POST'):
            form=createorderform(request.POST,instance=customer)
            if(form.is_valid()):
                form.save()
                return redirect('/')
        context={'form':form}
        return render(request,'app_name/placeorder.html',context)
    except:
        print("Error occurred : {exec}".format(exec=traceback.format_exc()))
```

What I am getting is all the users:

[image]

What I want is to only show the current user in drop down.

Please help or guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you `model=Order` have Form Meta, but instance you are giving of `form=createorderform(instance=customer)` customer , why so?

Comment: @shivankgtm well in my model my Order class is getting customer from Customer model: ``` customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) ``` and I am trying to pass to current logged in customer from my view so that i can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have kind of tried one solution and this one work, although I have tried it earlier but in between 100's of documents and solutions the easy one got lost :

In my **forms.py :**

```
class createorderform(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self._instance=kwargs.pop('instance',None)
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    #def __init__(self,instance):
    #    self.user = instance
    #    super().__init__(instance)

    class Meta:
        model=Order
        fields="__all__"
        exclude=['customer','status']
```

I excluded the customer field and instead populated it in my **views. py:**

```
def placeorder(request,i):
    try:
        products = Product.objects.all()
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=i)
        print("Customer:",customer)
        #form=createorderform(prod=products,cust=customer)
        form=createorderform(instance=customer)
        #form=createorderform()
        if(request.method=='POST'):
            form=createorderform(request.POST,instance=customer)
            if(form.is_valid()):
                curr_user = form.save(commit=False)
                curr_user.customer = customer
                curr_user.save()
                return redirect('/')
        context={'form':form}
        return render(request,'app_name/placeorder.html',context)
    except:
        print("Error occurred : {exec}".format(exec=traceback.format_exc()))
```

So I am overriding the save() and building my current logged in user in the view itself while saving it. It's storing the same user in db as well.

**EDIT:**

```
def placeorder(request,i):
    try:
        products = Product.objects.all()
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=i)
        print("Customer:",customer)
        #form=createorderform(prod=products,cust=customer)
        form=createorderform()
        #form=createorderform(instance=customer)
        if(request.method=='POST'):
            form=createorderform(request.POST)
            #form=createorderform(request.POST,instance=customer)
            if(form.is_valid()):
                curr_user = form.save(commit=False)
                curr_user.customer = customer
                curr_user.save()
                return redirect('/')
        context={'form':form}
        return render(request,'app_name/placeorder.html',context)
    except:
        print("Error occurred : {exec}".format(exec=traceback.format_exc()))
```

So I have change my form object and I am not sending my current logged in user to forms any more so just creating the object without "instance=customer" which got my current logged in user.

Now we don't need to handle the instance in init method of createorderform form :

```
class createorderform(ModelForm):
    #def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    #    self._instance=kwargs.pop('instance',None)
    #    super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    #def __init__(self,instance):
    #    self.user = instance
    #    super().__init__(instance)

    class Meta:
        model=Order
        fields="__all__"
        exclude=['customer','status']
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you'd want to pass the customer ID via an URL parameter when you could just POST it (e.g. as a hidden field if you need to).

Comment: @AKX Thanks for your response. But I am pretty new to django and will work on updating myself with best practices. Thanks for help and your response.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.views.generic import CreateView


class CreateOrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ['status', 'customer']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.customer = kwargs.pop('customer')
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.customer = self.customer
        return super().save(commit=commit)


class PlaceOrderView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    form_class = CreateOrderForm
    template_name = 'app_name/placeorder.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        return {
            **super().get_form_kwargs(),
            'customer': Customer.objects.get(user=self.request.user),
        }
```

should be enough.